# Find a formula that generates the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Find a formula which generates the following sequence.

$$15,20,25,30,35 \ldots $$

The answer is $5(n + 2) $

How? I know it comes from the formula $a_n = a_1 + (n - 1) d$, but I am not sure how they got the answer. Could someone please help me?

Comment: The answer...**to what**?

Comment: @Don, the answer to "find a formula that generates the following sequence".

Comment: I was almost sure of that, @GerryMyerson, yet I think students above 4th grade **must** be thorough in the way they write and stop being sloppy. This is why I asked, but now it never minds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between each of the terms is $5$, so we know that our formula should be:

$$ a_n = 5n + c $$

Where $c$ is a constant term which we have not yet found.

We know that:

$$ a_1 = 5 \cdot 1 + c $$
$$ a_1 = 5 + c $$

But we are given $a_1 = 15$, and we have:

$$ 15 = 5 + c $$
$$ 10 = c $$

So we get:

$$ a_n = 5n + 10 $$

Factoring:

$$ a_n = 5(n + 2) $$

Comment: thank you very much!...i totally understood it here

Answer (score 2):

$$15,20,25,30,35,\dots$$ They're all multiples of $5$, so divide by $5$ to get $$3,4,5,6,7\dots$$ Subtract $2$ to get $$1,2,3,4,5,\dots$$ but this is $n$. Add back the $2$, so $$3,4,5,6,7,\dots{\rm\ is\ }n+2$$ Multiply back the $5$, so $$15,20,25,30,35,\dots{\rm\ is\  }5(n+2)$$